# Apple Notification Server APNS - My Domain is Banned

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have an enterprise iPhone app which uses APNS to send notifications to users phones.  This was working fine up until recently when we had a huge expansion of users, now no notifications are being sent/received and I cannot connect to APNS server from PHP.

I am 99% certain the reason is because the domain I am sending APNS requests from has been banned due to Apple thinking I was trying a DDOS attack.  Reasons I think this:

- Code I was using to send APNS messages was not proper, it was opening then closing the connection in a loop.  This is the cause of the ban I believe. I have learnt the error of my ways since but too late right now.
- I uploaded my .pem file to another server/IP and used the exact same code to send notification and received to my phone successfully.
- I have run and openssl command to try and connect to APNS server from the believed banned server and it connects but returns 'write:errorno=104' along with other error lines.  Whereas with the other server I mentioned it returned the proper connection output along with cert output, ect., the normal.

So my reason for posting is I am stuck wondering how to get my domain removed from the ban list. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html This page states that it takes about an hour for the temp block to expire, I have made sure to not attempt a connection for over 12 hours and still not working. "This temporary block will expire if no connection attempts are made for about one hour."

Looking through Apple support channel I can not find the proper path to follow and I do not want to pay for professional services.

Anyone experience this before and now path to follow to get off banned list?  Or to even verify that you are on the banned list?

Comment: I would suggest you [log a TSI](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) There are two included with  your enterprise developer program membership. Apple may even credit the incident if the problem is on their side.

Comment: Yes, if I do not figure it very soon I will be logging a TSI.  Figured I would try other outlets before wasting one of the two included in enterprise.  Appreciate the input.